# Syntax highlighting C++ variable names that contain a $ sign

Tags: syntax-highlighting, c++

[Many C/C++ compilers](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Dollar-Signs.html) have a nonstandard extension that allows `$` to appear in variable names. In `c++-mode`, if I write

```
int main()
{
    int $a = 0;
}
```

Then `$a` doesn't get colored like a variable name, the syntax highlighting seems to break. However `int a$ = 0;` works. How can I make it work in the above case? Visual Studio Code seems to handle it in either place no problem.

Comment: I *think* this is probably a bug in the definition of `c-identifier-key` but I am *far* from sure about it. It's a complicated regexp, but I think it uses the usual rule that the identifier has to start with an `alpha` character or an underscore: `$` can only  come after that. Try reporting it with `M-x report-emacs-bug` and see if the devs think that it is a bug and whether it is worth fixing.

Comment: ... or maybe `c-identifier-start` instead of `c-identifier-key` - maybe...

Comment: Done, we'll see how it goes :)